# creating a formula with a minimum of multiple cells that does not exceed a certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I am pretty good with basic excel but I have a spreadsheet that I use to do payroll and I have the formula I need but in order for it to work I have to keep all the cells 0 if I don't have any data to enter in to it.

My payroll sheet must calculate the total of all hours entered but then I also have it calculating how much of those hours is overtime (our system calculates overtime after 10hr a day and 44hr a week) so my first column is just the standard sum of 7 cells but my second column must give me hour many of those hours are regular but it cannot exceed 10 hour of the total hours worked.

For example, if John worked 13 hours it needs to take 10 of those hours and put them towards regular. But it also needs to not exceed 44 hours. The formula is working but I give this as a template to the field staff to send in their time and they don't enter zeros so I want to find a better formula or at least fix this one. 
My formula to find out the regular hours is

`=MIN(MIN(B11,10)+MIN(C11,10)+MIN(D11,10)+MIN(E11,10)+MIN(F11,10)+MIN(G11,10)+MIN(H11,10),44)`

But the problem is if I have blank spaces without zeros it automatically puts the total to 44.

I'm just trying to figure out if there is a better formula or a way to fix mine to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use N function within MIN for each cell, i.e.

`=MIN(MIN(N(B11),10)+MIN(N(C11),10)+MIN(N(D11),10)+MIN(N(E11),10)+MIN(N(F11),10)+MIN(N(G11),10)+MIN(N(H11),10),44)`

That will give you zero when all cells are blank

If you want a shorter version try this "array formula"

`=MIN(SUM(IF(B11:H11>10,10,B11:H11)),44)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....or this one is a little longer but doesn't require array entry

`=MIN(SUMPRODUCT((B11:H11>=10)*10+(B11:H11)*(B11:H11<10)),44)`

Comment: I like the use of `SUMPRODUCT` without the need for array formula!